# Python: How to merge the same elements in an array?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have this array:

```
[['Amy', '2'],
 ['Amy', '2'],
 ['Amy', '1'], 
 ['Yoyo', '1'],
 ['Yoyo', '2'],
 ['Yoyo', '2']]
```

I want to make it like this:

```
[['Amy', ['2','2','1'], 
 ['Yoyo',['1','2','2']]
```

Is it possible? Do I need to first make it a list or dictionary?

Comment: Looks like you have a list of lists, not a numpy array. Or do you have arrays anyway?

Comment: The only difference between this one and the other question is that your key is just the first element of each list.

Comment: Thannks, it's originally an array, converting to list is okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `sorted`. `groupby` of `itertools` groups consecutive matching values.

```
data = [['Amy', '2'],
    ['Amy', '2'],
    ['Amy', '1'], 
    ['Yoyo', '1'],
    ['Yoyo', '2'],
    ['Yoyo', '2']]

import itertools

def extract_key(v):
    return v[0]

# itertools.groupby needs data to be sorted first
data = sorted(data, key=extract_key)

result = [
    [k,[x[1] for x in g]]
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, extract_key)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> lst = [['Amy', '2'],
...        ['Amy', '2'],
...        ['Amy', '1'],
...        ['Yoyo', '1'],
...        ['Yoyo', '2'],
...        ['Yoyo', '2']]
>>>
>>> import itertools
>>> [[key, [n for _, n in grp]] for key, grp in
     itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])]
[['Amy', ['2', '2', '1']],
 ['Yoyo', ['1', '2', '2']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def proc(l = []):
tmp = {}
for e in l:
    if tmp.get(e[0]) is None:
        tmp[e[0]] = []
    tmp[e[0]].append(e[1])
return tmp
```

if you can use dictionary.